# Is $A$ satisfying ${A^2} = - I$ similar to $\left[ {\begin{smallmatrix} 0&I \\ { - I}&0 \end{smallmatrix}} \right]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

Is $A$ satisfying ${A^2} =  - I$ similar to $\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}   0&I \\    { - I}&0  \end{array}} \right]$?

I wonder if there is an easy way to prove this. It seems related to symplectic matrices.

Any help will be appreciated:)

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is defined over the reals, and $A^2=-I_n$ then $n$ is even and
$A$ is similar to $\pmatrix{0&I_m\\-I_m&0}$ over the reals where $m=n/2$.

One can make $\Bbb R^{n}$ into a complex vector space via $(r+si)v
=rv+sAv$. So this has dimension $m=n/2$ over $\Bbb C$. Take a basis
 $v_1,\ldots,v_m$ of $\Bbb R^n$ as a $\Bbb C$-vector space. Then
$v_1,\ldots,v_m,Av_1,\ldots,Av_m$ is a real basis for $\Bbb R^n$.
Consider the matrix of $A$ with respect to this new basis...

Comment: what book you use for those two statemants? or you have them on your own mind?

Comment: @RezaHabibi Take the determinant: $\det(-I_n)=(-1)^n$, but $\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2\ge0$ in the real case. That is why $n$ must be even.

Comment: @RezaHabibi The complexification of real vector spaces is standard fare, found in many textbooks. The complexification of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is of course $\mathbb{C}^n$, so this answer is doing something very simple too complicated.

Comment: @RezaHabibi But anyhow, the complex eigenvalues of $A$ have to be $\pm i$. If $A$ is real, these eigenvalues come in complex conjugate pairs, and their corresponding eigenvectors too. Writing the eigenvectors as $u\pm iv$ with $u$, $v$ real vectors, you then have $A(u+iv)=i(u+iv)=-v+iu$, so $Au=-v$ and $Av=u$. That's taking care of *one* pair of eigenvalues $\pm i$.

Comment: @RezaHabibi Note that the statement is equivalent to saying there is a basis $u_1$, …, $u_n$, $v_1$, …, $v_n$ with $Au_k=v_k$ for each $k$. This is just the $n$-fold version of my previous comment. As you can see, the answer leaves out quite a bit of detail! (But I am upvoting it anyhow.)